# Make an array Javascript with a PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I have a ajax script that returns me an associative array list as follows:

```
array(24) {  
["id"]=>  
string(4) "3478"  
["joindate"]=>  
string(19) "2016-10-17 21:20:28"  
["ip"]=>  
string(12) "xxx.xxx.xx.xx"  
...  
}

array(24) {  
["id"]=>  
string(4) "3479"  
["joindate"]=>  
string(19) "2016-10-17 21:20:28"  
["ip"]=>  
string(12) "xxx.xxx.xx.xx"   
...  
}
```

HTML

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><b><u>key 1</u></b></th>
    <th><b><u>key 2</u></b></th>
    <th><b><u>key 3</u></b></th>
    <th><b><u>key 4</u></b></th>
    <th><b>etc...</b></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>value 1</td>
    <td>value 2</td>
    <td>value 3</td>
    <td>value 4</td>
    <td>etc...</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>value 1</td>
    <td>value 2</td>
    <td>value 3</td>
    <td>value 4</td>
    <td>etc...</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

My current javascript where formation is an ID and methode is my date

```
data += "data=" +formation+' '+methode; 
$.ajax({ 
        url: "core/display_lead.php", 
        type: "post", 
        data: data, dataType: "html", 
        success : function(code_html, statut){ 
            console.log(code_html); 
        }, 
        error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){ 
            console.log("La requête n'a pas aboutie..."); 
            console.log(resultat); 
            console.log(statut); 
            console.log(erreur);
         } 
});
```

how do I get the key to creating a table header, then only the value to fill it ?

For the moment I transmits data to Javascript with a simple PHP var_dump, there is a cleaner method, perhaps?

thanks a lot

Comment: YES! `json_encode($array);` will pass a JSONString to javascript that will convert to a javascript object/array either automatically or using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: But you added AJAX to your tags, so you already knew that Right?

Comment: Show us how you make your AJAX call i.e. your javascript

Comment: I edit the question ;)

Comment: You should add the code to your question instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: Never mind I did it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first change your PHP code to send back a JSON respose instead of a var_dump

```
<?php

    $all = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($req, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
         $all[] = $row; 
    }

    echo json_encode($all);
```

Now in your javascript, tell the .ajax functionality to expect JSON as a response

```
data += "data=" +formation+' '+methode; 
$.ajax({ 
        url: "core/display_lead.php", 
        type: "post", 
        data: data, 
        dataType: "json",           //<-- amended

        success : function(data, statut){ 
            console.log(data); 
        }, 
        error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){ 
            console.log("La requête n'a pas aboutie..."); 
            console.log(resultat); 
            console.log(statut); 
            console.log(erreur);
         } 
});
```

Now using this and @krasipenkov answer and a little look at the data using the javascript debugger you should be almost all the way there. The `data` parameter on your `success` method should now be a javascript native data type i.e an array or an object depending on the data you built in PHP and easy enough to process

> Afraid I really have to add this as well now I see your using the `mysql_`extension. Every time you use [the `mysql_`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
>    database extension in new code
>    **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
>   If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I have an error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 399(…)

How can I find the error ?

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing what you are actually doing

Comment: Just console.log(data). my return is a successive object like :

Comment: I guess you had better show us how you are building the data in PHP

Comment: i simply use : 

while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($req, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 echo json_encode($array);
}

Comment: See amended answer for suggesed method. Better to build an array of all the data and return it as one lump

Answer (score 1):

var_dump is meant for debugging purposes. if you want transfer data to another script / language, you rather go for json.

So you do something like (untested):

```
<script>
var myJavascriptVariable = <?php echo(json_encode($myPHPVariable)); ?>;
</script>
```

At the top of your script / website. After that you have the JS Variable `myJavascriptVariable` which holds your data.

You might also want to have a look at Plugins like "DataTables" for jquery (see: https://datatables.net ). Those handle the Table Creation and offer additional features like sorting and filtering.

Comment: Thats not a very elegant way of doing it, but

Comment: What do you mean? Imo the only way to do it, besides loading the data via ajax request (which returns JSON on the php end ... so in the end the same).

Answer (score 1):

You can json_encode the result returned by your php like that:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

after that you can parse it in javascript and iterate over it:

```
var html = '<table>';
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    var head = '';
    var row = '<tr>';
    if($i === 0) {
        head += '<thead><tr>'
    }
    $.each(item, function(key, value) {
        head += '<th><b><u>'+key+'</u></b></th>';
        row += '<td>'+value+'</td>';
    });
    if($i === 0) {
        head += '</tr></thead>'
    }
    row += '</tr>';
    html += head+row;
});​
html += '</table>';
```

and append the html variable to a html element.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the array to json_encode and pass the data to the javascript, I replicate your idea with mine:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='../assets/jquery/jquery-latest.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>
<?php
        $data_ = array(
            array(
                "id" => "3478",
                "joindate" => "2016-10-17 21:20:28",
                "ip" => "xxx.xxx.xx.xx"
            ),
            array(
                "id" => "3479",
                "joindate" => "2016-10-17 21:20:28",
                "ip" => "xxx.xxx.xx.xx"
            )
        );

        $json_data = json_encode($data_);
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var data_ = <?php echo $json_data; ?>;
                var html = '<table border="1">';
                    html += '<thead>';
                    html += '<tr>';
                        html += '<th>ID</th>';
                        html += '<th>JOINDATE</th>';
                        html += '<th>IP</th>';
                    html += '</tr>';
                    html += '<thead>';
                    html += '<tbody>';
                        for(var i = 0; i < data_.length; i++) {
                            html += '<tr>';
                                html += '<td>' + data_[i].id + '</td>';
                                html += '<td>' + data_[i].joindate + '</td>';
                                html += '<td>' + data_[i].ip + '</td>';
                            html += '</tr>';
                        }

                    html += '</tbody>';
                $("#div_data").html(html);
        });
    </script>


<body>
    <div id="div_data"></div>
</body>
```

Please bear with my html tags XD. Hope it helps.